# Terraform yaml config

Tags: yaml, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I have the following YAML config file:

```
AWSConfig:
  conformance_pack_templates:
    - Operational_Best_Practices_test1:
       - excluded_accounts:
           -  "closed"
           -  "staging"
    - Operational_Best_Practices_test2:
        - excluded_accounts:
            -  "opened"
```

I want to get all the "excluded" accounts **id** existing in my `AWS organization` that include the names specified in the lists.
I am using `data.aws_organizations_organization.org.accounts` to get all the accounts details under the `AWS organization`.
the `data source` output is :

```
  ([{
    "arn" = "arn:aws:organizations::example1:account/f-432145321/example"
    "email" = "test@example.com"
    "id" = "543632464532"
    "name" = "closed"
    "status" = "SUSPENDED"
  },
  {
    "arn" = "arn:aws:organizations::example2:account/f-43214431/example"
    "email" = "test1@example.com"
    "id" = "45321534214"
    "name" = "closed"
    "status" = "SUSPENDED"
  },
])
```

I need to filter all the accounts with the names specified in the lists, and to get the following list of objects format output:

```
[ 
  { template = Operational_Best_Practices_test1, 
    excluded_accounts = [ 543632464532, 45321534214, 54325413421 ]},
  { template = Operational_Best_Practices_test2, 
    excluded_accounts = [ 65465554365, 654365436543 ]}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [for with a condition](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html#filtering-elements) and the [`contains`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/contains.html) function in order to achieve this.

Given:

```hcl
variable "accounts" {
  default = [{
      "arn" = "arn:aws:organizations::example1:account/f-432145321/example"
      "email" = "test@example.com"
      "id" = "543632464532"
      "name" = "closed"
      "status" = "SUSPENDED"
    },
    {
      "arn" = "arn:aws:organizations::example2:account/f-43214431/example"
      "email" = "test1@example.com"
      "id" = "45321534214"
      "name" = "closed"
      "status" = "SUSPENDED"
    },
    {
      "arn" = "arn:aws:organizations::example3:account/f-43214431/example"
      "email" = "test1@example.com"
      "id" = "45321534215"
      "name" = "opened"
      "status" = "OPENED"
    },
  ]
}

output "test" {
  value = {
    for rules in "${yamldecode(file("aws_config.yml")).AWSConfig.conformance_pack_templates}" :
      keys(rules).0 => [
        for account in var.accounts : 
          account.id
        if contains(rules[keys(rules).0].0.excluded_accounts, account.name)
      ]
  }
}
```

This yields:

```hcl
test = {
  "Operational_Best_Practices_test1" = [
    "543632464532",
    "45321534214",
  ]
  "Operational_Best_Practices_test2" = [
    "45321534215",
  ]
}
```

---

This said, if you are the owner of the YAML and you are allowed to change the structure of it a bit, converting some of your lists into dictionaries, like this:

```yaml
AWSConfig:
  conformance_pack_templates:
    Operational_Best_Practices_test1:
      excluded_accounts:
        -  "closed"
        -  "staging"
    Operational_Best_Practices_test2:
      excluded_accounts:
        -  "opened"
```

You can simplify the terraform code by removing the need of the [`keys`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/keys.html) function:

```hcl
output "test" {
  value = {
    for label, rule in "${yamldecode(file("aws_config.yml")).AWSConfig.conformance_pack_templates}" :
      label => [
        for account in var.accounts : 
          account.id
        if contains(rule.excluded_accounts, account.name)
      ]
  }
}
```